# unexpected found nil on the line tableView.datasourse = self

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a navigationController and I have added a custom UIBarButtonItem. What I want to do is when the user tap my button , it present a viewController which has a tableView inside it.

For that ,I have written this :

```
let shopoingCarVC:shopingCartProductsList = shopingCartProductsList()
 self.navigationController?.pushViewController(shopoingCarVC, animated: true)
```

shopingCartProductsList is my ViewController I intended to navigate to and when It navigate to that It gave me unexpected found nil error at this line :

```
tableViewProducts.dataSource = self
```

I have done it before on my other viewControllers but I got this problem when navigating without segue and with using pushViewController mehod.

This is my targetViewCOntroller :

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import Haneke

class shopingCartProductsList: BaseViewController ,UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {


    @IBOutlet weak var ShopingCartProducts: UITableView!

    var products = dataService.instance.shopingCartProduct
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ShopingCartProducts.dataSource = self
        ShopingCartProducts.delegate = self
        self.view.backgroundColor = COLOR_BACKGROUND

    }




func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if let tblCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("shopingCart_cell") as? shopingCart_cell {
        if let prod = products[indexPath.row] as? productMD{
            tblCell.configCell(prod)
        }
        return tblCell
    }else{
        return shopingCart_cell()
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("products count \(products.count)")
    return products.count
}



       func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
        }


  }
```

What's wrong ?

Comment: please make sure you have connected the tableview datasource and delegate method to main view and implemented the required delegates and datasource methods .

Comment: @AvijitNagare ,I edited my question.This is what I have done so far

Comment: @sourav I have edited my question.Check the complete ViewController source.

Comment: @AvijitNagare my mistake of copying .

Comment: tableViewProducts & ShopingCartProducts name seems different .In which line you are getting error ?

Comment: and you have not register your nib name in view did load  e.g. let nibName = UINib(nibName: "shopingCart_cell", bundle:nil)
        ShopingCartProducts.registerNib(nibName , forCellReuseIdentifier: "ReuseCell")

Comment: @sourav , At this line ShopingCartProducts.dataSource = self and I'm using storyBoard

Comment: can  you check products contains value by using breakpoint? cell identifier in storyboard.

Comment: @AvijitNagare , I check it out , my tableView's cell got the right identifier and products array contains value . The problem is from setting the dataSource to self.

Comment: push method looks bug use ex.  let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)  missing instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier

Comment: @AvijitNagare THANKS A LOT , YOU SAVED MY LIFE. The problem solved.Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use are wrong while pushing viewcontroller user below code.

```
let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as LoginViewController self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

[image]

Set identifier in Identity inspector.